# How to pass variable from one web project to another in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I'm fetching some data from my database to a string variable in my first web project (WebApplication1), and I want to redirect the user to my second web project (WebApplication2) and my string variable too. In order to get this work, I tried a few different ways but didn't work. I couldn't redirect to another project. Thanks in advance.

I tried to use

```
Response.Redirect("~/WebApplication2/TestRedirect.aspx" + send)
```

(`send` is my  variable).

Comment: your redirect call needs a query string parameter, something like:
Response.Redirect("~/WebApplication2/TestRedirect.aspx?var=" + send)

In the Testredirect you can read the var from the querystring 
string variable = Request.QueryString["var"];

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about two different projects not two different web page, than it is not possible to do this from a single solution. Because Both projects have different HTTPContext.
But a solution can be found according to your needs.

For example, you can write  a string value to a text file or json file in your first project (**WebApplication1**), then get and read this string value from your other project (**WebApplication2**).

Or my suggestion is that it would be best to keep the value you want to use in both projects in a field in the database.